# Numpy replace values and return new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a function in `numpy` similar to `np.put` that returns a new array instead of modifying an array in place? Something like this:

```
def put_copy(arr, ind, v, mode="raise"):
    arr_copy = arr.copy()
    np.put(arr_copy, ind, v, mode)
    return arr_copy

arr = np.arange(5)
print put_copy(arr, [0,2], [-44,-55])
# [-44   1 -55   3   4]
```

Comment: What you have defined looks fine...

Comment: @wim I just wanted to know if numpy has a function for this already

Comment: You may be able to do it in one step with `np.where`

Comment: It looks good.  At the module level, I think it's more readable to keep copy (np.copy) and assignment operations separate,  so I don't have to learn so many special functions. Numpy alone is already bigger than anything I could learn and remember.  In your own code it's different.  You'll always know what you intended.